# What are the benefits to using BIO_printf() instead of printf()?

Tags: c, openssl

I have been reviewing example code for using OpenSSL and in every example I locate, the creator has chosen to use BIO_printf() to write things to stdout instead of printf().

I have taken their code, removed the openssl/bio.h header declaration, and changed all calls to BIO_printf() to regular printf() statements.  The programs ran with identical results.

The problem I'm grasping with is why these coders use BIO_printf() when it takes a lot more to setup than just using printf().  You have to include another header (which will increase program size), you need to set the file pointer to the stream you want to write to.  Then you can print your message to stdout.  It seems a lot more complicated than using printf().

When I do a search on BIO_printf() it lists possible man pages for BIO_printf (3), but none of the pages actually contain any information!

I decided to do a benchmark test on both methods.  I looped `printf("Hey\n");` 1,000,000 times.  Then I did it for `BIO_printf(fp, "Hey\n");`.  I only timed the BIO_printf() statement and not the setting up of the file pointer (which would have increased the time).  The difference came out to printf() being ~4.7x faster than using BIO_printf().

Why are they using it?  What is the benefit?  It's my understanding that in programming you either want code to be simple or efficient, and in the case of BIO_printf() it's neither.

Comment: In my experience the OpenSSL functions are there for safety and abstraction. The BIO_printf function either protects information from leaking or simplifies working with BIO structures or maybe both.

Comment: Because of all the problems with OpenSSL, there is a project running that very much simplifies OpenSSL, and removing things like BIO_printf() was among the first things on the list. In other words, someone thought BIO_printf was a good idea, but it isn't.

Comment: I do generally agree with the sentiment that BIO is beyond the scope of what a SSL library should be doing. In my own code I don't use them at all, I use my own communication channels and just use the non-BIO versions of OpenSSL functions.

Comment: @gnasher729 did you have a specific product in mind? There are many SSL toolkits out there.

Comment: From the "bio.doc" section of [ssleay.txt](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/doc/ssleay.txt):  "The BIO library is a IO abstraction that was originally inspired by the need to have callbacks to perform IO to FILE pointers when using Windows 3.1 DLLs."  It's foolish to criticize a piece of software without understanding its history.  At the time, I'm sure the BIO abstraction solved all sorts of portability problems.

Answer (score 2):

In general, a BIO might not be writing to stdout.

You can have a BIO that writes to a file, or null, or a socket, or a network drive, or another BIO, etc.

By using the BIO_printf family, the code can easily be changed to have its output sent to a different location or another BIO which might do some further filtering and then pass the output onto wherever else.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by others, `BIO` can be stacked contrary to `FILE`. `snprintf()` and `vnsprintf()` were added in C99. OpenSSL/SSLeay is older than this. Hence, the SSLeay developpers had to write their own implementation. Unfortunately, having a little used implementation leads to the performance issues described by the OP or to [CVE-2016-0799](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2016-0799).